# Random Image and get winner (Processing)

Tags: processing

Hi I'm building a slot machine game and am having a few problems I'm pretty new with processing.

I've made this code and need the "wheels" to be random but they all have the same image (vertically)

I realise you won't be able to see the images so here's some links if you want them.

http://tinypic.com/r/i1jq7t/6 (diamond1)

http://tinypic.com/r/29fe5cg/6 (cherry1)

http://tinypic.com/r/sen1jo/6 (bell1)

```
int numFrames = 3;  // The number of frames in the animation
int frame = 0;
int spincount = 0;
int state = 0;
PImage[] images1 = new PImage[3];

PImage[] images2 = new PImage[3];

PImage[] images3 = new PImage[3];

void setup() {
  size(1080, 720);
  frameRate(12);

  // wheel 1 
  images1[0]  = loadImage("bell1.png");
  images1[1]  = loadImage("cherry1.png"); 
  images1[2]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");


  // wheel 3
  images3[0]  = loadImage("cherry1.png");
  images3[1]  = loadImage("bell1.png"); 
  images3[2]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");


  // wheel 2
  images2[0]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");
  images2[1]  = loadImage("bell1.png"); 
  images2[2]  = loadImage("cherry1.png");

} 

void draw() { 
  background(o);
  //test state to see if I should be spinning
  if(state == 1) {
    spin();   
  } 

}

//if a key is pressed then set the wheel to spin 
void keyReleased() {
 state = 1;
}


void spin() {
    //spin for 5 times the break out  
  if (frame == 3) { 
    frame = 0; 
    spincount ++;
      if (spincount == 10) { 
        state = 0;
        spincount = 0;
        //check if its a win and do stuff
        winner();
      }   
  }
    // wheel 1  
    image(images1[frame], 20, 0);
    image(images1[frame], 20, 170); //this is the image to test
    image(images1[frame], 20, 340);

    // wheel 2

    image(images3[frame], 200, 0);
    image(images3[frame], 200, 170); //this is the image to test
    image(images3[frame], 200, 340);

    // wheel 3

    image(images2[frame], 400, 0);
    image(images2[frame], 400, 170); //this is the image to test
    image(images2[frame], 400, 340);


    frame ++;

  }  



 void winner() {

    //are the names of the images the same   
    //if ((images3[frame].get(0,0)) == (images2[frame].get(0,0)) == (images1[frame].get(0,0))) {
       // display a question from you list of questions by generating a random number and selecting the text

       // wait for an answer
      for (int i = 0; i < 400; i = i+1) {
        if (keyPressed == true) {
          // whats the key is it correct
        }
        if (i > 400) {
        //display times up
        }
      }
    }
 // }
```

I'm also having issues with getting the "winner" (if the horizontal images's pixel in the left hand corner match go onto "winner".

I'd really appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: What language are you using? Also, your tags aren't really relevant.

Comment: This is a lot of code. Consider editing it into a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

In the draw function, you are probably wanting to draw a black background, but you currently have the letter "o" instead of the number 0 (zero).

You probably want to draw the current wheel state to the screen in your draw function, right now you just have a black window unless you are spinning.

You can't compare colors directly.

Here is some modified code to get it working:

```
int numFrames = 3;  // The number of frames in the animation
int maxSpin = 10;
int frame = 0;
int spincount = 0;
boolean spinning = false;
boolean checkWinner = false;
PImage[] images1 = new PImage[3];
PImage[] images2 = new PImage[3];
PImage[] images3 = new PImage[3];

void setup() {
  size(1080, 720);
  frameRate(12);

  // wheel 1 
  images1[0]  = loadImage("bell1.png");
  images1[1]  = loadImage("cherry1.png"); 
  images1[2]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");


  // wheel 3
  images3[0]  = loadImage("cherry1.png");
  images3[1]  = loadImage("bell1.png"); 
  images3[2]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");


  // wheel 2
  images2[0]  = loadImage("diamond1.png");
  images2[1]  = loadImage("bell1.png"); 
  images2[2]  = loadImage("cherry1.png");
} 

void draw() { 
  background(0);
  //test state to see if I should be spinning

  // wheel 1  
  image(images1[frame], 20, 0);
  image(images1[frame], 20, 170); //this is the image to test
  image(images1[frame], 20, 340);

  // wheel 2

  image(images3[frame], 200, 0);
  image(images3[frame], 200, 170); //this is the image to test
  image(images3[frame], 200, 340);

  // wheel 3

  image(images2[frame], 400, 0);
  image(images2[frame], 400, 170); //this is the image to test
  image(images2[frame], 400, 340);

  if (spinning) {
    spin();
  }

  //this draws circles stroked in the color of the pixel at their center
  //this is just to show how the code works, you can remove this
  noFill(); // make the circles transparent
  loadPixels(); // required before using pixels[]
  color wheel1 = pixels[170*width+20];
  color wheel2 = pixels[170*width+200];
  color wheel3 = pixels[170*width+400];
  stroke(wheel1);
  ellipse(20, 170, 10, 10);
  stroke(wheel2);
  ellipse(200, 170, 10, 10);
  stroke(wheel3);
  ellipse(400, 170, 10, 10);
}

//if a key is pressed then set the wheel to spin 
void keyReleased() {
  if(!spinning) spinning = !spinning;
}


void spin() {
  //spin for maxSpin times then break out  

  if (frame == numFrames-1) { 
    spincount ++;
    if (spincount == maxSpin) { 
      spinning = !spinning;
      spincount = 0;
      //check if its a win and do stuff
      winner();
    }
    else frame = 0;
  }
  else frame++;
}  



void winner() {
  loadPixels();
  color wheel1 = pixels[171*width+21];
  color wheel2 = pixels[171*width+201];
  color wheel3 = pixels[171*width+401];
  if(hue(wheel1) == hue(wheel2) && hue(wheel2) == hue(wheel3)) println("winner");
  else println("not a winner");
}
```

This inclues your desired method of checking the corner colors on the images, but I would recommend just keeping track of which image is currently being displayed in the center.

I hope this at least gets you moving in the right direction.